# Same certSigningRequest for all certificates?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, app-store-connect

Higuys,

I got a really simple question. We got a lot of apps and when i have to create the push certificates, do i have to request a .certSigningRequest each time per app ?
Or can i use the same for all my certificates creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same one, there should be no problem with that.